# Cython PXD does not seem to be used for PYX file

Tags: c++, cython

I am trying to learn cython by implementing a linear interpolator from C++ to Python.
I am trying to use PXD header files for the final Intepolator object so that it can be reused in other methods / classes down the line, so I want to have the PXD header file available.

I have a cpp_linear_interpolation.cpp and cpp_linear_interpolation.h that work fine, the interpolator gets instantiated with two vectors of double (x and y) as input.

There are my files

**cy_linear_interpolation.pxd**

```
# distutils: language = c++

import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "cpp_linear_interpolation.h":
    cdef cppclass cppLinearInterpolation:
        cppLinearInterpolation(vector[double], vector[double]) except +
        vector[double] interp(vector[double]) except +

        vector[double] m_x
        vector[double] m_y
        int m_len
        double m_x_min
        double m_x_max
```

**py_linear_interpolation.pxd**

```
from cy_linear_interpolation cimport cppLinearInterpolation

cdef class LinearInterpolation:
     cdef cppLinearInterpolation * thisptr
```

**py_linear_interpolation.pyx**

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from cy_linear_interpolation cimport cppLinearInterpolation


cdef class LinearInterpolation:
    # cdef cppLinearInterpolation *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self,vector[double] x,vector[double] y):
        self.thisptr = new cppLinearInterpolation(x, y)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def interpolate(self,vector[double] x_new):
        return self.thisptr.interp(x_new)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy


setup( name = 'Cython_LinInt',
       ext_modules=[Extension("cython_linear_interpolation",
                              sources=["py_linear_interpolation.pyx", "cpp_linear_interpolation.cpp",],
                              language="c++",
                              include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]) 
       ],
       cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

compiling with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for x64

I get the error message

> Cannot convert 'cppLinearInterpolation *' to Python object

If I move

```
cdef cppLinearInterpolation * _thisptr
```

to the pyx file (the commented out line in py_linear_interpolation.pyx), it compiles and run, but then I cannot access the pointer from another cython file.
Ideally I would be able to instantiate the interpolator from python, and use it as argument for other python / cython functions. 
I am sure I must be doing something stupid, but I have been blocked on that problem for a little while now and have not found yet the solution...

EDIT: there was a typo in py_linear_interpolation.pyx, now corrected
EDIT 2: the same type was in py_linear_interpolation.pyd, the member name is thisptr, the code still isn t compiling and I get the same error. It does not seem that the cython compiler recognizes that self.thisptr is not a python object and should be a pointer to a cppLinearInterpolation

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
self.thisptr = new cppLinearInterpolation(x, y)
```

To:

```
self._thisptr = new cppLinearInterpolation(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Czarek. It was a type of mine, the code still isn't working with the correct thisptr name

Comment: with the latest changes, I now get py_linear_interpolation.pyx:12:5: C class 'LinearInterpolation' is declared but not defined

Comment: @Damien022 The import I mentioned is not needed. See [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types). You are not providing enough details to debug this further. I suspect that you use "import" instead of "cimport" in your other Cython files.

Comment: I have done a more basic example and still running with the same problems. should I post the new example as a new question or fully edit my original question?

Comment: I've yet to get a response on a [Cython question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926482/cython-compileerror-when-attempting-to-compile-extension-type) regarding a compile error. You may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing `__cinit__` to

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.thisptr = new cppLinearInterpolation(x, y)
```

Since `cpp_linear_interpolation.h` and other files were not given, I could not test this myself.

Comment: Thank you for this,. I have still not found a solution to the problem and I will try to write a small and complete new question on SO.

Comment: I've yet to get a response on a [Cython question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926482/cython-compileerror-when-attempting-to-compile-extension-type) regarding a compile error. You may be able to help.