# CompileError when attempting to compile extension type

Tags: python, compiler-errors, compilation, cython

I’m trying to follow this [tutorial](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html) on using pyx, pxd, and cimport to create and use extension types.

When compiling the Cython file in terminal, I am getting an error that I don’t know how to correct for:

`cdef class CythonClass:` in the pyx file is indicated as the line of error.

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1056, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: CythonClass.pyx
```

I am using Cython version .25 (and have tried other versions as well, each installed with `pip install cython`) on MacOS Sierra. Python version is 2.7.10.

As suggested, I installed gcc (Command Line Tools for Xcode 8.2), but am still receiving the error.

**File contents:**

pxd:

```
cdef class CythonClass:
    cdef:
        list list1
        dict d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6
```

pyx:

```
cdef class CythonClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []
        self.d1 = {}
        self.d2 = {}
        self.d3 = {}
        self.d4 = {}
        self.d5 = {}
        self.d6 = {}
```

setup.py (invoked by `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in terminal):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize(["CythonClass.pyx"]))
```

At least presently, I'll attempt to compile without using pxd files, since the compilation went through for the extension types. However, the main function that imports the extension types is not compiling (with error: `extTypeName is not a type identifier`).

Comment: Hi - I just tried this in my machine but I actually did not get any error in compilation. I using Windows 10, Python 3.5 64bit, with Cython version 0.24.1. I'm not sure what is the cause of your problem. Sorry!

Comment: How did you install Cython? The log makes it look like you are using the system Python and install Cython system-wide but that does not tell how. The Cython doc http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html suggest to install Apple's XCode to obtain a version of gcc.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, Cython was installed with `pip install cython`. I retried after installing gcc with the same result (but I'll run a quick test to verify gcc is properly integrated).

Comment: Hi, I also tested and found no error. The problem might be in annoying details like the filenames in the path or in the presence of invisible characters in the source code. Can you attach the files and provide a full log of the error?

Comment: More detail: a hyphen `-` in the modulename is not allowed in Python.

Comment: New to Cython, I may be confused about how I’m approaching this. I thought I didn’t need pxd files (and the pyx files compile without them (with the definitions in the class)). However, then there is an error `CythonClass is not a type identifier`. I may need to post another question (which I’ll link to if I do), as I need to verify that I can even use these extension types in a function defined with cdef.

Comment: You need the pxd file only if you want to import the cython module into another cython module. But then you don't import `CythonClass.pxd` in `CythonClass.pyx`.

Comment: I assume I can't just place all extension types in one pyx file with the main cython function (I remember trying this, but perhaps incorrectly).

Comment: You can do that, it is not an issue. The main function will have to be called from Python anyway. Cython generates modules only and not executables. You Python "driver program" can be only a few lines long in that case.

Comment: I probably need to post another question, as (when moving the extension types to the main pyx file) I receive an error `AssertionError: unexpected type int and base type tuple object for indexing`. But who knows if that corresponds to a different issue. I'll double check everything before moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: I posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-doing-so-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at:
[Cythonize by Command Line](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html)

Read the page but more specifically go to the section: "Compiling with the cythonize command".

You create the .pyd or .so file:

```
cython yourmod.pyx
cythonize -a -i yourmod.c
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Why is calling Cythonize on the command line any different to using setup.py. It'll run the exact same commands. Whatever problem the asker of this question was having will be _exactly the same_ when called from the command-line.

Comment: I do not know.  There are two ways to do this.  The first was not working for me so I tried option 2.  Option 2 worked (!).  But since initially posting this I gained some additional insights.
Trying imports, relative or absolute, using Spyder, there seems to be a bug.  I get an error when using Spyder and Cython imports but if I run the same code via the command line it works.
I've not seen a bug report on this issue yet and I have some work to do to characterize the issue before I could put in a bug report.